# eww cannot follow links displayed after keyword search

Tags: eww

I have emacs 25.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 and have been trying to browse with its built in `eww` browser.

I start with `M-x eww`.

Then I type in my search keyword. DuckDuckgo displays a list of search results as expected. However if I navigate (using `C-n`, `C-p`, `C-f`, and `C-b`) to a link and try to follow it (`return`) DuckDuckgo fails, displaying:

> 'Oops, there was an error. Please try again.
>
> If it persists, please email ops@duckduckgo.com'

Any ideas as to how to diagnose this problem? Essentially I cannot browse with `eww`, although firefox and google-chrome work fine (whether I use DuckDuckgo or google search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem occurs because DDG is doing a JavaScript redirect to the selected link.  You can disable this by adding "kd=-1" into the URL query string.  This doesn't help specifically with running eww (although I'm sure it's easy enough to fix) but you can work around it by using a custom function to kick off a DDG search:

```
(defun duckduckgo (search-string)
  "Search Duck Duck Go for SEARCH-STRING.

Use kd=-1 to turn off redirecting - seems to be required in order
for result links to work in DDG."
  (interactive "sDuckDuckGo for: ")
  (let ((url-format "https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%s&kd=-1"))
    (eww (format url-format (url-hexify-string search-string)))))
```

Edit - in fact it looks as if you ought to be able to just set eww-search-prefix to something like "https://duckduckgo.com/html/?kd=-1&q=".

Comment: I tried both of your proposed solutions, they both work Thanks!

Comment: NP.  FWIW I've also raised it as an Emacs bug (https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26148), so perhaps it will be fixed in the next release.